# locally connected separable metric space but not completely metrizable

Tags: general-topology

Can we find an example of a space which is locally connected separable metric space without isolated points but not completely metrizable?

Answer (score 3):

Let $X$ be the subspace of $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ consisting of the open upper half plane plus the rational points on the horizontal axis, i.e.,
$$X=\{(x,y):y\gt0\}\cup\{(x,0):x\text{ is rational }\}\subset\mathbb R\times\mathbb R.$$
$X$ is a locally connected separable metric space with no isolated points, but is not completely metrizable because it is not a $G_\delta$ subset of $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R.$

Comment: Which topology are you taking on $X$?

Comment: Subspace of $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R.$